# Creating bindings splitting window in 4 parts

Tags: linux, terminal, tmux

I'm pretty new to tmux and would like to know if it's possible to split a terminal window in 4 parts by a single command like `Ctrl+b, \`. I can do it with `Ctrl+b, "` and then `Ctrl+b, %` but this is kind of verbose and I work with 4-window screen very often (it's my favorite terminal view). I mean this:

[image]

***QUESTION***: Is it possible to configure such a binding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add custom bindings in your `~/.tmux.conf` if you don't have one yet, go ahead and create it. Here's the syntax for a custom binding to split your tmux into quadrants like you wanted above:

`bind - split-window -v \; split-window -h \; select-pane -t 0 \; split-window -h \;`

Put that in `~/.tmux.conf` and the binding I set it to is `Ctrl+b, -`

[Here's](http://www.hamvocke.com/blog/a-guide-to-customizing-your-tmux-conf/) a decent guide on how to use your `.tmux.conf`

Comment: Wow, I'm very impressed. Thank you very much!